# Why does this not split the genres properly? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to find the best-rated genres for this [data set](https://www.kaggle.com/isaactaylorofficial/imdb-10000-most-voted-feature-films-041118). I started off splitting the genres because there were multiple genres in most rows. Then I sorted through the genres and their scores calculating the average score for each genre. I then update the data frame with each genre and their average score. However, there are repeating genres in the list for some reason and I'm not sure why.

```
dataGenre = data
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Genre":dataYearScore['Genre'], "Score": dataYearScore['Score']})
df5 = df5.assign(Genre=df5['Genre'].str.split(',')).explode('Genre').reset_index(drop=True)

genre_list5 = []
avg_scores5 = []

for genre in df5["Genre"].unique():
    genre_list5.append(genre)
    avg_scores5.append(df5.loc[df5["Genre"]==genre, "Score"].mean())

plt.bar(genre_list5, avg_scores5, width = 0.8)
plt.xlabel('Genre')
plt.ylabel('Average Score')
plt.xticks(rotation=65)
plt.title('Average Score for Each Genre')
plt.show()


df5 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Genre":genre_list5, "Score": avg_scores5})
df5
```

I believe the problem is either in line 3 or the for loop but I'm not sure whats doing it.
Any help at all would be greatly appreciated :)

Update:

The data can be found here https://www.kaggle.com/isaactaylorofficial/imdb-10000-most-voted-feature-films-041118

It's imported with

```
data = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')
```

I don't really need the graph, I just need the data frame to have a column with genres (no repeats) and their average score.

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Genre":genre_list5, "Score": avg_scores5})
df5
```

This is checked using the code above^

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired output

Comment: I updated the post. Does that provide you with enough information?

Comment: So do you only want the first genre in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there might be some spaces before or after the `comma` separating two genres, hence you need to use the regex pattern `\s*,\s*` with `Series.str.split` to properly split the `Genres`:

```
s = data[['Score']].assign(
    Genre=data['Genre'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*')).explode('Genre')
avg = s.groupby('Genre')['Score'].mean()
```

Plotting the average ratings:

```
avg.plot(kind='bar', width=0.8)
plt.ylabel('Average Rating')
plt.title('Average Score for Each Genre')
```

Result:

[image]